# Red letters error, when i try to install Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Ok, so I'm trying to install Django like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPmkl4jtYgA

I have latest Python (3.5.1). I set "user variables" like in video. When I try to run `pip install django` in windows cmd I get this error

What it may be ? 
[image]

Comment: maybe need sudo pip install?

Comment: Yes, cmd.exe's ability to copy/paste is charitably described as primitive, but you should still paste in the text (as written, it looks like the error you get is -.-.-.-.-.-.-^.- which isn't a link)

Comment: Please don't link to a screenshot. Paste the error, here, as text

Comment: Also, given that this looks like an OS issue versus a programming one, you might want to take this over to SuperUser

Comment: @Baterson ... its windows ... so no that should not be the case ... (same @Foon)

Comment: so use "run as administrator"

Comment: the real problem is that you changed where python is installed ... by default it would be installed in `C:\Python35`  which is accessible by any logged in user ... you(@DanteW) changed the location to be under `C:\Program Files` which is only writable by admin ...

Comment: Run as Administrator worked ! Thx guys !

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install django in global environment but using normal user.
You should runas Administrator and do the `pip install django`, or using [virtualenv](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/).